# REST API best parctice. GET and update if field comes in request. How to recieve fields

Tags: rest

I have:
`GET https://host/clients/1324/emails` (1234 is enterpriseId)

New requirements:

- Potential clients: will be saved by nationalId, so GET method will keep recovering ok
  `GET https://host/clients/12345678H/emails` (12345678H is nationalId)
- New clients: if potential clients become clients we need to update _id mongo document from nationalId to enterpriseId (by replacing doc because _id cannot be updated)

Question:
Since someone becomes a client, front app will send both enterpriseId and nationalId. The first time backend recieves both should update and return updated doc transparently.
So, as it is a GET where should front send each id to follow best practices?
Is it ok with best pratices? `GET https://host/clients/1324/emails?nationalId=123456879H`

Comment: Why do you need to pass in both IDs? It seems to me your system must have some link between the prospective client record and the actual client record created from it. Provided the IDs are unique you should be able to correlate them yourself in the API code.

Comment: the first time after becoming client, mongo doc is {_id: 12345678H, emails:[]}. I have to turn it into {_id: 1234, nationalId:"12345678H", emails:[]}. So I do not have any connection between ids, that is what i want to get dynamicly while users call the app.